# TPL : one or more error occured

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Environment : C#, VS2010, .NET 4.0

I have error message below. However, If I try to run one more, then it works. I'm going to check why it works like this. Would you please any comment ?

- Run application program.
- Execute tplTest method.
- occur Error
- Execute tplTest method.
- it works.

**Error message :**

[9008] Error Form1::tplTest Error: MESASGE[one or more error occurred.]
[9008] SOURCE[mscorlib]
[9008] TRACE[Location: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Code Snippet :

```
private void tplTest(List<string> listFileNames)
      {
          try
          {
              var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();

              List<Task<TResult>> tasks = new List<Task<TResult>>();

              foreach (string item in listFileNames)
              {
                  Task<TResult> t_MethodA = Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(tpSharpness, item);
                  tasks.Add(t_MethodA);
              }

              try
              {
                  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // <-- Error Occurred

                  foreach (Task<TResult> item in tasks)
                  {
                      if (item.IsCompleted)
                      {
                          TResult _result = item.Result;
            // TODO Something
                          //...
                      }
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  exceptions.Enqueue(e);
              }

              if (exceptions.Count > 0)
                  throw new AggregateException(exceptions);              
          }
          catch (AggregateException exception)
          {
              foreach (Exception ex in exception.InnerExceptions)
                  log.AddErrorLog(this.Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, string.Format("Error: MESASGE[{0}]\r\nSOURCE[{1}]\r\nTRACE[{2}]", ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace));
          }
      }

     private TResult tpSharpness(object arg)
      {
          SharpnessTask _tpSharp = new SharpnessTask();
          return _tpSharp.Task();
      }
```

Comment: Could you post the full exception, including its inner exceptions and the stack trace? Without that, I think this is impossible to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the `AggregateException` in the `try catch` around the `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`.  This is where the aggregate exception is being thrown from.

Once you catch and handle the exceptions you can move on to the next part of the code and the `foreach` loop.